# How do you set the min-height of an iframe from c# code-behind?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, height, code-behind, css

```
    HtmlGenericControl iframectrl = new HtmlGenericControl("iframe");
    iframectrl.Attributes.Add("src","blah blah blah");
    iframectrl.Attributes.Add("width","100%");
    iframectrl.Attributes.Add("min-height", "100%");
```

I am creating an iframe dynamically (as seen above) and putting it on a tab panel which is also created dynamically.  I can set the height of the tab container and the tab panel from my PageLoad function, but I cannot get the height of the iframe to set correctly no matter what I do.  I am trying to avoid using Javascript to set the height.  I have tried adding an attribute for this, but it doesn't work.  If I create the iframe control in my aspx page, I can set min-height and it works fine.  Should I create my iframe in a PreLoad or PreRender function or is there something better?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding as a CSS style.

```
iframectrl.Attributes.Add("style", "min-height:100%,width:100%;");
```